# Too many tcp connections of a websocket app

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, websocket, tcp

I'd like to maintain connected clients on my server

client:

```
let interval;
const connect = () => {
    sock = new WebSocket();
    // if we successfully connect we stop re-trying
    clearInterval(interval);
};

sock.onclose = () => {
    // we try to continuously maintain the connection
    interval = setInterval(connect, 60000);
};
```

server:

```
const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wsServer.on("connection", async (conn, req) => { 
    
    const id = uuid.v4();
    
    onlineTable.addById(id);
    
    conn.on("close", () => {
        onlineTable.removeById(id);
    });
});
```

But I found there's a lot more ESTABLISHED tcp connections `netstat -tnulpao | grep port | awk  '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c` than the entries count in my database, on my production server.

Maybe I did somethings wrong? I tried disconnecting the wifi, starting a lot of clients on my local machine. However I cannot replicate it.

I have no idea on to continue now. Can you give me some hints?